# Pretty-print AudioFormatID in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, core-audio

Apple SDKs have some enumerations that are designed to be "pretty" in memory, e.g. Core Audio's AudioFormatID:

```
enum {
    kAudioFormatLinearPCM               = 'lpcm',
    kAudioFormatAC3                     = 'ac-3',
    kAudioFormat60958AC3                = 'cac3',
    kAudioFormatAppleIMA4               = 'ima4',
    kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC                = 'aac ',
    ...
```

However, Xcode displays them as plain integers, i.e.:

[image: Xcode rendering an AudioFormatID]

Answer (score 1):

To change this, assign a summary format to an AudioFormatID field you're seeing in the Debug Area:

[image: Edit Summary Format... menu]

and enter `{(FourCharCode)($VAR)}`:

[image: Summary Format]

(Notice the screenshot shows `lpcm` now.)